# Gnip issue - while creating a job -- urllib2.URLError

Tags: python, json, curl, urllib2, gnip

I am trying to create a job using Gnip Historical Powertrack API.

I am getting issue with the urllib..

```
import urllib2  
import base64  
import json  
UN = '' # YOUR GNIP ACCOUNT EMAIL ID  
PWD = ''  
account = '' # YOUR GNIP ACCOUNT USER NAME  
def get_json(data):  
    return json.loads(data.strip())  
def post():  
    url = 'https://historical.gnip.com/accounts/' + account + '/jobs.json'  
    publisher = "twitter"  
    streamType = "track"  
    dataFormat = "activity-streams"  
    fromDate = "201510140630"  
    toDate = "201510140631"  
    jobTitle = "job30"  
    rules = '[{"value":"","tag":""}]'  
    jobString = '{"publisher":"' + publisher + '","streamType":"' + streamType + '","dataFormat":"' + dataFormat + '","fromDate":"' + fromDate + '","toDate":"' + toDate + '","title":"' + jobTitle + '","rules":' + rules + '}'  
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (UN, PWD)).replace('\n', '')  
    req = urllib2.Request(url=url, data=jobString)  
    req.add_header('Content-type', 'application/json')  
    req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)  

    proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://proxy:8080', 'https': 'https://proxy:8080'})  
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)  
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)  
    try:  
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)  
        the_page = response.read()  
        the_page = get_json(the_page)  
        print 'Job has been created.'  
        print 'Job UUID : ' + the_page['jobURL'].split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]  
    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:  
        print e.read()  

if __name__=='__main__':  
    post()
```

## this is the error I am getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gnip1.py", line 37, in <module>
    post()  
  File "gnip1.py", line 28, in post
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)  
  File "/home/soundarya/anaconda-new-1/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/home/soundarya/anaconda-new-1/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/home/soundarya/anaconda-new-1/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/home/soundarya/anaconda-new-1/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/soundarya/anaconda-new-1/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/home/soundarya/anaconda-new-1/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

## I even tried through the curl command:

When I tried running the below one in terminal, I am getting error - ServiceUsername is not valid.

curl -v -X POST -uname -d '{"title": "HPT_test_job","publisher": "Twitter","streamType":"track","dataFormat":"activity-streams","fromDate":"201401010000","toDate":"201401020000 ","rules":[{"value": "twitter_lang:en (Hillary Clinton OR Donald)","tag": "2014_01_01_snow"}]}' 'https://historical.gnip.com/accounts/account_name/jobs.json'

### This is the exact output msg:

Error retrieving Job status: {u'serviceUsername': [u'is invalid']} -- Please verify your connection parameters and network connection *

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. see if it helps

```
import urllib2
from urllib2.request import urlopen 
u = urlopen ('http:// .........')
```

Comment: I am getting urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized -- after changing the changes which you have mentioned (urlopen)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3.5 you should use the library urllib.request which is the newer version of urllib2. Notice however that this changes a few things in the code including print (which should be in parentheses) and the need to transform some of the string results into bytes. [Here](https://github.com/chagag/Gnip_python_historical_job_Request) you can look at all the required changes in code adapted to python 3.5